# Views Attachment repeating on each category page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I know I'm just beginner about Views Attachments - I think I learned how to put a sticky article teaser on Category page Above all others; - but as there are many numbered Category pages i.e. ?page=1 ; page=2 etc. - and so my Attachment appears on every page -

but how to make it only on base URL page and not all?

p.s. my term/ category pages are all Views / Replicas